# Trigger download "event" of GCPs SSH-in-Browser from a script?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

On the top right corner of the SSH-in-Browser terminal for a Compute Engine, there is a download button. What I'd like to do is trigger this functionality directly from the VM terminal.

**Why?**

Every once in a while, I'm requested to make a copy of a database for any reason. So far, this requires me to 1) Make the dumps, 2) Zip the dumps, 3) Download the zip and 4) Send it to whoever requested it. I decided to automate this since its becoming more frequent.

So far, 1 and 2 are done, and I would usually leave it at that, but I'm wondering if I can just trigger the "downloading function" from the script that handles the dumps and zipping, just to save me a few clicks and writing down the path. For example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

here=$(pwd)

mkdir /home/me/back
mkdir /home/me/back/data
/home/me/saveTables $1
/home/me/saveRecords $1
cd /home/me/back
zip -r $here/$1.zip ./* > /dev/null
sudo rm -dr /home/me/back

# and then download it with something like 
# 'gcpdk' is made up just for example purposes
gcpdk --download $here/$1.sql
```

Is this possible from the SSH-in-Browser at all? So far I'm guessing that the download function is not accessible from within the VM terminal, but I have not found documentation about the downloads themselves yet, so I can't tell. Or perhaps this is something I should do with a different tool?

By the way, I can't copy files to Cloud Storage (Lack the permissions) so at least for now, that is not an option.

Any help, link or confirmation of whether or not this is doable is welcome.

And just to be extra sure: This is not something critical. Its just me being lazy. Cheers!

Comment: You can create automated or on-demand backups for your database and store them in a custom location, using [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#automated-backups). Did you try to use Cloud Functions to automate your process?

Comment: Thank you for your time! We are not currently using Cloud SQL, the database is with the app within the VM. The reason is budget. I haven't properly looked into functions since our usage of this service is antiquate, more similar to monolithic apps on in-premise servers, but I will take the time to look into them.